# Why maxima cannot solve these equations

Tags: maxima

I have several equations that specify relationships between elements of an ellipse (minor and major semi axis, eccentricity, pericenter and apocenter distance, focal parameter).
I want to find other formulas that express each of those elements through combinations of all other elements. solve() works perfectly fine on some combinations, but not the other.
What is the difference between those cases and how I can make it solve?

```
    sys:[b=a*sqrt(1-e^2),p=a*(1-e^2),c=a*(1+e),d=a*(1-e)];
    solve(sys,[a,b,e,p]);
    solve(sys,[a,b,e,c]);
    solve(sys,[a,b,e,d]);
    solve(sys,[a,b,p,c]);
    solve(sys,[a,b,p,d]);
    solve(sys,[a,b,c,d]);
    /* solve(sys,[a,e,p,c]); -- gives error */
    /* solve(sys,[a,e,p,d]); -- gives error */
    /* solve(sys,[a,e,c,d]); -- gives error */
    solve(sys,[a,p,c,d]);
    solve(sys,[b,e,p,c]);
    solve(sys,[b,e,p,d]);
    solve(sys,[b,e,c,d]);
    solve(sys,[b,p,c,d]);
    solve(sys,[e,p,c,d]);
```

Here is output for "good" and "bad" case:

```
(%i5) solve(sys,[a,b,c,d]);
                                        2
                  p           sqrt(1 - e ) p          p          p
(%o5)   [[a = - ------, b = - --------------, c = - -----, d = -----]]
                 2                 2                e - 1      e + 1
                e  - 1            e  - 1

(%i6) solve(sys,[a,e,p,c]);

algsys: tried and failed to reduce system to a polynomial in one variable; give up.
 -- an error. To debug this try: debugmode(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `to_poly_solve` on these. It is a share package -- you have to enter `load(to_poly_solve);` before calling it.

Comment: I have maxima 5.25.1 and this package is nowhere to be found in it. Is it some kind of new package distributed with later builds or should I download it separately?

Comment: In versions before 5.27, try `load(to_poly_solver)` (note: `solver` instead of `solve` there). The function was always named `to_poly_solve` so the name of the file was adjusted to be the same instead of slightly different. If possible, use the latest version (5.32), since there have been many bug fixes and other improvements.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I am still curious, as to why the solve() failed and when is the difference between those cases. They do not look any special at first glance.